# Bash script - create dir(s), copy specific files while changing name

Tags: bash, scripting, directory

I am working on writing a bash script that completes the following:

-creates 3 directories in the test directory named dir1, dir2, and dir3
-copies all files starting with "alpha" to each of the newly created directories such that the names now start with the directory name

for example, the output should be: dir1-alpha.txt

I know cp can't copy to multiple directories all at once, just from multiple sources, so I am struggling to come up with a strategy for doing that.

Could someone please help point me in the right direction with these parameters?

Comment: Use a loop.  `for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do for f in alpha*; do cp $f $dir/$dir-$f; done; done`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_names=('dir1' 'dir2' 'dir3')
path_to_files='/tmp/tmpfiles/'

for i in ${dir_names[@]}; do
    echo "Creating $i and copying over files..."
    mkdir $i
    for f in $(ls $path_to_files); do
        cp $path_to_files/$f $i/$i-$f
    done
done
```